# Did griffin know about the beleith's activation?

Tags: berserk

I just binge watched all 25 episodes of the berserk anime and I am curious to if Griffith knew that the Beleith was activating when the eclipse started? When they were in the river he thought to himself

> Stay away from me... If you so much as touch my shoulder we can never go back.

Did that have any significance?

I haven't read the manga and from what I've researched there is no second season to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking of chapter 72-73 of the manga, if you want to look it up (Volume 12).

Griffith sits in the lake, picks up the Behelit and remembers what Zodd and Wyald told him. "Use it. Call them. Our guardian angels!". As the solar eclipse happens, he most definitely realizes.

He then crawls backwards, away from the rest of the Band, hoping to not draw <s>them</s> **Edit**: Guts into the eclipse.

On the matter of sequels, the actual series has no second season. There are the 2013 movies (Berserk: The Golden Age) or the 2016 series ("Berserk 2016").

Comment: "hoping to not draw them into the eclipse."  That sounds like an awfully nice interpretation of Griffith's final moments before ascending.  Griffith was always dead set on sacrificing anything and anyone to achieve his goal of ruling his own country, including his entire army.  It was the shocking realization that he couldn't bear the loss of Guts, one of his stepping stones, and the idea that he could actually be defeated and left by one, that caused his downfall.  Griffith's retreat always struck me as "they might try to stop this, but I cannot let them get in my way again".

Comment: Uh, yeah, I don't know why I wrote "them" over Guts really. I was even looking through the book at the time, and Guts (and no one else) is in half of every panel on the actual page. I'll update my answer to better reflect this. It's very obvious that Griffith at least knows what's going to happen - even his helmet sweats in the final panel.